# Argument state after the thread is completed

Tags: java, multithreading

Question:

Suppose we pass a ArrayList to Runnable constructor. In the Runnable class we add certain strings to the list. Now we run the Thread from main() and wait for its completion. After the Thread execution is over, is it possible that when we iterate the list in main() we get the strings(values) added to the list by the Runnable class because the reference to the Arraylist is created in Heap.
but when I iterate the list, it is empty. Could anyone explain why the list is empty.

Thanks in Advance:
Vijay K

```
public class GetListThread implements Runnable{

private List<String> names;

public GetListThread(List<String> names) {
    super();
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        try {
            names.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,10) + "A");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //System.out.println(names);
}
}


public class TestThread {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    GetListThread g = new GetListThread(names);
    Thread t = new Thread(g);

    t.start();
    System.out.println(t.getState());

    for(String s : names){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Re, "we run the Thread...and wait for its completion."  No.  Your code does NOT wait for the thread to complete.  Peter Lawrey said the same thing, but just in case he did not make it clear...  The way to wait for a thread to complete is to call `t.join()`.  The join() method will not return until the thread has finished.  It also _synchronizes_ with the termination of the thread.  Without synchronization, there is no guarantee that your main thread will be able to see what the other thread wrote even if the other thread _is_ finished.

Answer (score 2):

> After the Thread execution is over, is it possible that when we iterate the list in main() we get the strings(values)

Yes, the collection is not thread safe, there is no guarantee you will ever see anything. You might even see `null` values i.e. where the size is correct but the elements are not.

> Could anyone explain why the list is empty.

However in you case, you are not waiting, so there is almost no chance it will have all its elements.

The thread takes time to start, so it is highly unlikely you will even see the first element added.